# Bash if statement with multiple brackets not accepted

Tags: bash

Trying to convert from ksh to bash. Below line keeps throwing error

```
if [ (( ! -z $(echo $STR_CON | grep '^ *-.') )) || ( -z $STR_CON ) ] then
    print -u2 "no connect string"
fi
```

Tried changing the brackets to `[[` and `((` added `;` still below error. What could be the error here?

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Bash version

```
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Comment: Are you comparing to a fixed string `^ *-.` or do you want to check for strings with one of these characters?

Comment: @Socowi this also worked when added a `;`

Comment: @WalterA Frankly im also not sure. What i could understand is that its checking if the variable CONSTR is empty or not.

Comment: Check your conditions in `if [ ! -z "$(echo $STR_CON | grep '^ *-.')"  ] | [ -z "$STR_CON" ]; then` by testing things like `echo 'teststring with spaces' | grep '^ *-.'`

Comment: `[` is a command, not part of the `if` statement's syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert those conditions to this in `bash`:

```
if [[ -z $STR_CON || $STR_CON =~ ^ *-. ]]; then
    print -u2 "no connect string"
fi
```

Comment: `grep` part also not required? Could you also explain the meaning pls?

Comment: Also i  put single quote like this ` '^*-.' `

Comment: `=~` is the regex matching operator in Bash. See third item on this page:  https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html

Answer (score 0):

OP is not sure about the requirements of the code he is converting.
Perhaps it is not a connect string when it is empty or has one of the mentioned chars in it. 
Just for fun:

```
sed -rn 's/^$|.*([\^ *-.]).*/no connect string/p ' <<< ${STR_CON}
```

And a normal solution

```
grep -Eqv "^$|[\^ *-.]" <<< "${STR_CON}" || 
   { echo "no connect string";  echo "Perhaps return here"; }
```